# MAMP PRO apache couldn't start - no error logs

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

Just upgraded Mac OS with the latest Sierra security update and MAMP PRO cannot start apache anymore. I re-installed MAMP PRO but nothing does.

Thanks for your help!!